# How to calculate Manhatten distance between 2 lists containing 3 sublists

Tags: python, distance

I am trying to calculate the Manhattan distance '[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]. The goal is for it to end up as [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 0]]. but i am very unsure on how to do so. Ive tried doing this:

```
    def manhattan_distance(self):
    dist = 0
    for i in range(len(self.board)):
        dist += abs(self.board[i] - self.DEFAULT_BOARD[i])

    return dist
```

self.board = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
self.DEFAULT_BOARD = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 0]]

Currently this is the one idea ive had that might solve the problem, but wont. Ive tried searching all over the internet for a solution that i could use or learn, but could not find one

Comment: ""wont ... solve the problem" is not a problem specification.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  As far as I can see, this should get a run-time fault, because you're trying to subtract two lists -- not to mention the undefined symbols and syntax errors.  What do you expect for the distance resulting from these two boards, and what did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider this approach:

```py
import math
import itertools

def distance(a, b):
  """distance between two lists of numbers of same length"""
  return math.sqrt(sum([a1**2 + b1**2 for a1, b1 in zip(a, b)]))

def taxi_dist(a, b):
  """takes two lists of lists"""
  dist = 0
  for el_a, el_b in itertools.izip_longest(a, b):
    dist += distance(el_a, el_b)
  
  return dist

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(taxi_dist([[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,0]]))
```

Comment: oml haha. ill try my best haha

Comment: Ive been looking for an answer like this for ages.
got a Manhattan distance of 31.814740669363964